# DoubleAnimation/Storyboard doesn't stop

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, controls

global vars:

```
private DoubleAnimation AnimateCursor = new DoubleAnimation();
private Storyboard CursorAnimation = new Storyboard();
```

initializing part:

```
AnimateCursor.From = 0;
AnimateCursor.To = 1150;
AnimateCursor.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
AnimateCursor.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

Storyboard.SetTargetName(AnimateCursor, "timeCurLine");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(AnimateCursor, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));

CursorAnimation.Children.Add(AnimateCursor);
```

and finally I add this code that controls animation start and stop:

```
public void StartNavCursor() => CursorAnimation.Begin(timeCurLine);
public void StopNavCursor() => CursorAnimation.Stop(timeCurLine);
```

so my problem is why stop function doesn't working?

I suppose that I misunderstand something about animation class or storyboard thing but I cannot understand now.

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to specify that the animation is controllable when you start it:

```
CursorAnimation.Begin(timeCurLine, true);
```